# Second Monitor not Working after installing nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, nvidia-prime

I saw there are a lot of questions about this particular subject, but none of the previous answers helped me.
I just installed Ubuntu 18.04, so I'm new to it.
After the installation, the second monitor was blurred, and wasn't showing the image correct, but the `xrandr` command recognized the HDMI cable.
After that I installed the nvidia drivers, and it stopped working at all.
The output from `xrandr` is:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+  39.99  
   1680x1050     59.93  
   1280x1024     59.93  
   1440x900      59.93  
   1280x800      59.93  
   1280x720      59.93  
   1024x768      59.93  
   800x600       59.93  
   640x480       59.93
```

I tried everything I could find online, like switching between `lightdm` and `gdm3`, installing the drivers with the `autoinstall` command, I tried multiple versions of drivers, the most recent one being `nvidia-440`. If I purge the nvidia drivers, or I switch to the nouveau driver, the Xrandr recognizes the HDMI port, but the monitor is still not working.`lshw -c display` is showing both of the monitors, so it's not a hardware problem.

My system is:

Processor:AMD® Ryzen 5 3550h with radeon vega mobile gfx × 8
GPU: Nvidia Gtx 1050

I also tried with multiple versions of ubuntu(16.04,19.10) and the problem was the same, just with other drivers.
The ubuntu is dualbooted with Windows 10 and the second monitor is working in Windows.

Thank you!